# Naming convention for variables containing file path or its parts

Tags: path, naming-conventions, filepath

What are standard or most self-descripting variable names for variables with following values? (Consider them from perspective of `File.Ext`)

```
// Windows environment
var0 = "C:\Folder_A\Folder_B\Folder_C\File.Ext"
var1 = "C:\"
var2 = "C:\Folder_A\"
var3 = "C:\Folder_A\Folder_B\"
var4 = "C:\Folder_A\Folder_B\Folder_C\"
var5 = "File"
var6 = "Ext"
var7 = ".Ext"
```

This is what comes to my unexperienced mind:

0. `FullPath`
1. `Drive`
2. ???
3. ???
4. `ParentFolderPath`
5. `Filename`
6. `Extension`
7. `FullExtension`

Also what is Windows standard or best practice for storing folder paths - with or without the last `\`?
Same for extension - with or without `.`?

Answer (score 0):

```
filePath = "C:\Folder_A\Folder_B\Folder_C\File.Ext"
rootDirectory = "C:\"
directoryPath = "C:\Folder_A\"
anotherDirectoryPath = "C:\Folder_A\Folder_B\"
aThirdDirectoryPath = "C:\Folder_A\Folder_B\Folder_C\"
filenameSansSuffix = "File"
fileSuffix = "Ext"
anotherDefinitionOfFileSuffix = ".Ext"
```

It is more natural to define directory paths without a trailing backslash.

When it comes to file extensions I usually include the dot. Also, in Windows Batch scripting, for instance, the modifier `~x` results in the file extension *including* the dot (when i tried it).

> %~xI  Expands %I to a file name extension only.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for

Comment: I have never saw word "suffix" used as description of the file extension in Windows environment. In [.NET Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=net-6.0) it's always referenced as "extension"

Comment: @Lluser They have the same meaning but the word *suffix* is shorter which is a nice property for identifiers.